# How to crawl asp.net gridview's second or third page

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl this URl

http://www.fbr.gov.pk/SROsAmending.aspx?Department=Sales Tax

Here below is my code, but its not working. how to crawl its second or third page of paginated gridview ?

```
 <code>
 WebRequest request = 
 WebRequest.Create("http://www.fbr.gov.pk/SROsAmending.aspx?Department=Sales Tax");

 request.Method = "POST";

 string postData = "__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdArticals";

 postData = postData + "&__EVENTARGUMENT=Page$3";

 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

 request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

 Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

 dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

 dataStream.Close();

 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

 string test = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

 dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

 reader.Close();
 dataStream.Close();
 response.Close();

</code>
```

Comment: This is the correct URl

Comment: This is the correct URL

http://www.fbr.gov.pk/SROsAmending.aspx?Department=Sales%20Tax